# How can we restrict user to allow execution of specific command in Redis in redis-cli

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

Hi I am using Redis on RHEL 7, and want that users having access to **redis-cli** can only able to execute few specific commands not all the commands in **Redis**.

Here my purpose is that users having access to **redis-cli** can only perform some monitoring related commands e.g. ***cluster nodes*** , ***info***  not other keys read write commands to protect data.

As per Redis documentation it's not clear how to provide authorization bases access to user on commands.
Or is there any other way to deal with this?

Comment: https://redis.com/blog/getting-started-redis-6-access-control-lists-acls/

Comment: Check out Redis ACL https://redis.io/topics/acl